# LIRC does not start after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

If I compile LIRC with [`this patched lirc`](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=49903&sid=f8cd3d90f03786d0ed04c6591665991d#p390615) followed by install using `make install` it works fine and launches without any error. However, after a reboot the same command fails with following error :

```
root@NAS:~# lircd --device=/dev/ttyACM0 --driver=usb_irtoy
lircd: can't open or create /var/run/lirc/lircd.pid
lircd: No such file or directory
root@NAS:~#
```

Any ideas what could be the reason for this ?

Comment: What are the permissions at `/var/run/lirc`? The directory/file exist at all?

Comment: `/var/run/lirc` is `root` with `0755` and `lircd.pid lircm lircd` files inside them are `root` with `0644` permission. The folder is no longer there after a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. We need to manually create `/var/run/lirc/` directory on every boot. I edited the lirc **init.d** script as below which creates the directory if not there using code `[ -d "/var/run/lirc" ] || mkdir -p "/var/run/lirc"`.

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# This is an init script for Debian 2.1 Slink distribution.
# Copy it to /etc/init.d/lirc and type
# > update-rc.d lirc defaults 20
#


test -f /usr/local/sbin/lircd || exit 0
test -f /usr/local/sbin/lircmd || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ -d "/var/run/lirc" ] || mkdir -p "/var/run/lirc"
    echo -n "Starting lirc daemon: lircd"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircd -- --listen --driver=usb_irtoy --device=/dev/ttyACM0
    echo -n " lircmd"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircmd
    echo "."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping lirc daemon: lircmd"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircmd
    echo -n " lircd"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircd
    echo "."
    ;;
  reload|force-reload)
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal 1 --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircd
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --signal 1 --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircmd
    ;;
  restart)
    echo -n "Stopping lirc daemon: lircmd"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircmd
    echo " lircd"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircd -- --listen --driver=usb_irtoy --device=/dev/ttyACM0
    sleep 1
    echo -n "Starting lirc daemon: lircd"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircd -- --listen --driver=usb_irtoy --device=/dev/ttyACM0
    echo -n " lircmd"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec /usr/local/sbin/lircmd
    echo "."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/lircd {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```